# Fakevim replaces everything instead of one at a time replacement (:%s/A/B/gc)

Tags: qt-creator, fakevim

I am using Fakevim in Qt Creator 4.5.0. One of my most frequently used commands in normal vim is :%s/exprA/exprB/gc . However, in Fakevim, this works just like :%s/exprA/exprB/g - it replaces everything, and doesn't let me scan through and choose which replaces to carry out.

I Googled this topic, and couldn't find a similar bug report, or setting that I need to change in Qt Creator. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, FakeVim doesn't support `c` substitution flag. It ignores any unrecognized flag. That's why in FakeVim `:%s/exprA/exprB/gc` works same as `:%s/exprA/exprB/g`.

Comment: Anyway to change settings so it recognizes 'c'?

Comment: I don't think this can be emulated in Qt Creator without fixing the code. For some advanced Vim functionality, it's possible to set shortcut to open current document momentarily in GVim (see [Using External Tools](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-external.html)).